# How to clean up useEffect hook when using async function within

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I've got a useEffect hook in which I create a Firebase RTDB listener. The function I used to create an async within the hook is called fetchData.

When the component unmounts I've got to somehow delete the listener. I've tried to make it within the hook return function but I do not know how to make it properly.

I've also tried to return ref and listener from fetchData to use it in return eventully but it did not help.

Could you please help me?

This is my hook snippet:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log('DIDMOUNT')
      const ref = await db.ref(url)
      const listener = ref.on('value', sn => {
        const val = sn.val()
        const fetched = []
        for (let id in val)
          fetched.push({ id, ...val[id] })
        setData(fetched)
      })
    }

    fetchData()

    return () => {
      console.log('UNMOUNT')
      ref.off('value', listener)
    }
  }, [user])
```

Comment: You declared `ref` inside `fetchData()` therefore it is not available in the outer scope, where your `return` is. Try moving the variable declaration outside `fetchData()`; something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8hx92z6w/

Comment: Just a side note: as it is possible that `fetchData()` fails and `ref` is never initialized, you might want to modify slightly the returned function, from `ref.off('value', listener)` to `ref && ref.off('value', listener)` (check whether `ref` is not `null` or `undefined` before trying to  use it)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just modified the code. I feel so grateful that you've helped me to resolve this issue.